# POM packaging option jar to war change error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

Hi I'm trying to change the packaging option from jar to war in my pom.xml. But when everi changes this leads to an error. So that i am not able to create the war file for my spring boot application.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>AsBuilt-MS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AsBuilt-MS</name>
    <description>Demo project for AsBuilt-MS Application</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.domain.AsBuiltMS.AsBuiltMsApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-binding</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

error message

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'AsBuilt-MS'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.2.2
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.2.2
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.2.2
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:3.2.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:3.2.2
```

so can anyone know how to solve this.

Comment: Install Maven locally (if you didn't) then try: `mvn clean package` from the command line. If it is OK, then run Maven -> Update project from Eclipse.

Comment: @EugenCovaci not working . Same error.

Comment: Are you behind a network proxy?

Comment: yes. This is the company policy

Comment: You need to configure the proxy in the Maven's settings.xml

Comment: i have done the same too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191146/discussion-between-eugen-covaci-and-pranav-ms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are behind a corporate proxy, you need to configure two proxy entries in `settings.xml`: one for http another for https protocols.

```
<proxy> 
<id>http-proxy</id> 
<active>true</active> 
<protocol>http</protocol> 
<username>proxyuser</username> 
<password>proxypass</password> 
<host>proxy.host.net</host> 
<port>80</port> 
<nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts> 
</proxy> 

<proxy> 
<id>https-proxy</id> 
<active>true</active> 
<protocol>https</protocol> 
<username>proxyuser</username> 
<password>proxypass</password> 
<host>proxy.host.net</host> 
<port>80</port> 
<nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts> 
</proxy>
```